# how to use distinct and group with sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have created one query that is for parent summary list. here i just want to get records multiple time because mutiple entries to another table : here it is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetParentList](@searchtext varchar(200) = null)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select distinct * from
    (select *, right('00000' + CAST([PK_PID] AS varchar(5)) ,5) as ID,(select count(*) from parentstudentassign ps where ps.ParentID = p.PK_PID) as Kids
    from parents p
    left join parentstudentassign ps on ps.ParentID = p.PK_PID

    where (@searchtext is null  or p.[PK_PID] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or p.[ParentName] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or p.[Gender] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or p.[Ocuption] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or p.[Address] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or p.[MobileNo] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or p.[EmailID] like '%'+@searchtext+'%') 
    order by PK_PID asc) as test1
    group by Kids
END
```

here i dont't want entries as multiple time:

[image]

and this is error occurs :

[image]

whats' going wrong here. please help me to out.

Comment: Just read and try to understand, what error message says and you should be step closer to solution. Hint: shift `order by` into outmost part of query.

Comment: ok. i understant it there no need for left join. just comment up it and go

Comment: What is wrong here?  Let's see, you have `select *` and `group by`.  That's broken.  You have `order by` in a subquery.  That's broken.  I would suggest you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: Please, post text. Only images if *absolutely* necessary. For all of what you show there is a text alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetParentList](@searchtext varchar(200) = null)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select distinct * 
    from
    (
        select *, right('00000' + CAST([PK_PID] AS varchar(5)) ,5) as ID,(select count(*) from parentstudentassign ps where ps.ParentID = p.PK_PID) as Kids
        from parents p
        left join parentstudentassign ps on ps.ParentID = p.PK_PID

        where (@searchtext is null  or p.[PK_PID] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                                or p.[ParentName] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                                or p.[Gender] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                                or p.[Ocuption] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                                or p.[Address] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                                or p.[MobileNo] like '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                                or p.[EmailID] like '%'+@searchtext+'%') 
    ) as test1
    order by PK_PID asc
END
```